# JTable is not showing. How do I fix it?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMAT3.jpg)

In the picture I attached(link) above, JTable is supposed to be shown under forward, Backward, and Remove buttons with JTable headers: X / Y / Width / Height

But, it is not. Can anyone please help me? what am i doing wrong here ?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Whiteboard extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Whiteboard();
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String[] petStrings = { "Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Pig" };

    public Whiteboard() {
        JButton setColor = new JButton("Color");
        JPanel colorPanel = new JPanel();
        colorPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        colorPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(colorPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        colorPanel.add(setColor);

        JButton addRect = new JButton("Rect");
        JButton addOval = new JButton("Oval");
        JButton addLine = new JButton("Line");
        JButton addText = new JButton("Text");
        JPanel addPanel = new JPanel();
        addPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        addPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(addPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        addPanel.add(addRect);
        addPanel.add(addOval);
        addPanel.add(addLine);
        addPanel.add(addText);

        JTextField setText = new JTextField("");
        JComboBox<String> changeFont = new JComboBox<String>(petStrings);
        JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
        textPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        textPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(textPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        textPanel.add(setText);
        textPanel.add(changeFont);

        JButton sendForward = new JButton("Forward");
        JButton sendBackward = new JButton("Backward");
        JButton removeObj = new JButton("Remove");
        JPanel orderPanel = new JPanel();
        orderPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        orderPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(orderPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        orderPanel.add(sendForward);
        orderPanel.add(sendBackward);
        orderPanel.add(removeObj);

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] { "X", "Y", "Width", "Height" }, 0);
        JTable infoTable = new JTable(tableModel);
        JScrollPane tablePanel = new JScrollPane();
        infoTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(infoTable.getPreferredSize());
        infoTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        tablePanel.add(infoTable);
        tableModel.addRow(new String[] { "TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3", "TEST4" });

        JPanel control = new JPanel();
        control.setLayout(new BoxLayout(control, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        control.add(colorPanel);
        control.add(addPanel);
        control.add(textPanel);
        control.add(orderPanel);
        control.add(tablePanel);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setLayout(new BoxLayout(canvas, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        JPanel window = new JPanel();
        window.add(control);
        window.add(canvas);

        getContentPane().add(window);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Whiteboard");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could reduce this to a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

```
tablePanel.add(infoTable);
```

Don't add components directly to a `JScrollPane`. The component should be added to the `JViewport` of the scroll panel.

Instead you can use:

```
JScrollPane tablePanel = new JScrollPane(infoTable); // easiest way,
```

or

```
tablePanel.getViewport().setViewportView( infoTable );
```

Also, don't use the `Canvas` class. That is an AWT component. You should be using a `JPanel`.

Comment: so, I need to delete the whole line tablePanel.add(infoTable); or just need to delete infoTable inside of parentheses ? and I already have JScrollPane tablePanel = new JScrollpane();, so i just need to add infoTable inside of parentheses ?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by not use the Canvas class  ? Do i have to delete or change anything for that?

Comment: @trueno, Why do you ask question like that without first trying it?. Why would you wait around for an hour or more for a reply when you can answer your own question in a minute by simply trying it? So the answers to your two comments are: 1) did you try it? 2) use a JPanel.